# Derive Secret 3DES Key from a Master 3DES Key in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, 3des, secret-key, key-generator

I have generated a 3DES Key the following way:

```
KeyGenerator masterKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
masterKeyGenerator.init(112);
SecretKey masterKey = masterKeyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Now I need to derive a new key using the above generated master key but I also need to use a random bytes(diversification data) in this key derivation process.

I can derive another Secret Key using the earlier generated Master Key only(the below code example) but apparently it is not the way, because I cannot find a way how use master key together with additional diversification data to derive a new key.

```
SecretKeyFactory secondKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
KeySpec myKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(masterKey.getEncoded());
SecretKey secondKey = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
```

Someone suggest me a code example in Java on how use master key together with additional random bytes[](diversification data) to derive a new key?

Comment: Due to DES weak keys, this is really tricky. Are you sure you cannot use AES which doesn't have those problems? Then you could just use HKDF. Also, it might be important to know why you want to do this.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thank you for your reply. My master key must be 3DES key. And the key which I need to derive using the master key will then be used to perform encryption using the TDES in CBC mode.

Comment: @ArtjomB. or do you mean my second key can be AES(master_key, diversification_data[])? Do you have code example with AES?

Comment: @zaph, but I do not have an answer to my question yet.

Comment: See [encrypt-then-mac flow](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44531/suggestions-for-improving-encrypt-then-mac-flow)